# How to create a new column basis on calculative condtions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

There are two column A and column Aging. Required to create a new column called simulator  with condition (mean+std) of column A. For example for all Aging==2,  simulator should be calculated basis the corresponding values in column A .

I tried the the given below code however when i change the Aging value, the simulator value does not change. Provided below is the reference data and the code i tried.

```
# seed the pseudorandom number generator
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint
# seed random number generator
seed(1)
# generate some random numbers
x=pd.DataFrame(randint(0, 10, 20),columns=list('A'))
# reset the seed
seed(1)
# generate some random numbers
x['aging']=pd.DataFrame(randint(1,5,20),columns=list('z'))

x['simulator']=np.where(x['aging']==2,x.A.mean()+x.A.std(),0)
x['simulator']=np.where(x['aging']==4,x.A.mean()+x.A.std(),x['simulator'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.where` evaluates your values **first** and *then* chooses those values based on the condition. So in both cases `x.A.mean() + x.A.std()` is calculated over the **entire DataFrame**, and being the same DataFrame in each case, the chosen value is the same.

The only difference is that the value is only set to the rows where `x['aging']==2` or `x['aging']==4`, depending upon the condition.

If you want the column to be the `mean` + `std` within each aging, use `groupby` + `transform`:

```
gp = x.groupby('aging')['A']
x['simulator'] = gp.transform('mean') + gp.transform('std')

    A  aging  simulator
0   5      2   7.088436
1   8      4   6.835113
2   9      1   9.041928
3   5      1   9.041928
4   0      4   6.835113
5   0      2   7.088436
6   1      4   6.835113
7   7      2   7.088436
8   6      4   6.835113
9   9      1   9.041928
10  2      1   9.041928
11  4      2   7.088436
12  5      1   9.041928
13  2      4   6.835113
14  4      2   7.088436
15  2      1   9.041928
16  4      3   7.621320
17  7      2   7.088436
18  7      3   7.621320
19  9      1   9.041928
```